# Have a container tag with react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to have composable container I can render like:

```
<Container><Heading>{heading}<Heading></Container>
```

Given that `Container` is

```
<div class="container something">
  {contents}
</div>
```

and `Heading2` is

```
<h2 class="heading something">{heading}</h2>
```

Is it possible to do this?

I know enough syntax to do `container(heading2(heading)` or `<Container contents={heading_element}>` but they dont nest like JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Children elements are available to the class by `this.props.children`. Learned it in a roundabout way.

```
var Container = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className="container">
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  }
});

var Heading2 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h2>{this.props.children}</h2>
  }
});

var Child2 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Container><Heading2>This is it.</Heading2></Container>
    </div>
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `props` and you can even prop a component.

```
var Header = React.createClass({ 
  render: function() {
    return (
       <h2 class="heading something">{this.props.heading}</h2>
    );
  }
});

var Container = React.createClass({ 
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div class="container something">
           {this.props.contents}
       </div>
    );
  }
});


var header = <Header heading="test" />
<Container contents={header} />
```